# How to Pass parameters to callback functions in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function like this

```
$("#button1").on("click", clickEvent);

function clickEvent(someParameter){
  console.log(someParameter);
}
```

How Can I pass some value (for ex: 1) to clickEvent function in that situation ?

Comment: Have you tried this: $("#button1").on("click", clickEvent(some_value));

Comment: @Alen: That only works if `clickEvent()` returns a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments are always the event, but you can use a  closure to get more data into your callback

```
$("#button1").on("click", function(){clickEvent(1);});

function clickEvent(someParameter){
  console.log(someParameter);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> If a data argument is provided to .on() and is not null or undefined,
>   it is passed to the handler in the event.data property each time an
>   event is triggered. The data argument can be any type, but if a string
>   is used the selector must either be provided or explicitly passed as
>   null so that the data is not mistaken for a selector. Best practice is
>   to use a plain object so that multiple values can be passed as
>   properties.

```
function greet( event ) {
  alert( "Hello " + event.data.name );
}
$( "button" ).on( "click", {
  name: "Karl"
}, greet );
$( "button" ).on( "click", {
  name: "Addy"
}, greet );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't control which parameters get passed. It's always the event object which gets passed into the handler function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Function.prototype.bind`, but you'll lose the `this` argument:

```
$("#button1").on("click", clickEvent.bind(null, 1));

function clickEvent(someParameter){
    console.log(someParameter);
    // in here, `this` no longer refers to the button
}
```

Or use closures in a slightly different way:

```
$("#button1").on("click", makeClickEventHandler(1));

function makeClickEventHandler(someParameter){
    return function(event) {
        console.log(someParameter);
    }
}
```

But tobyodavies' answer is the most applicable solution here.

Answer (score 0):

if the parameters are all like your example primitive and constant you can simply do this:

```
function addClickEvent(param){
    var clickEvent=Function('var param = "'+param+'"; alert(param);');
    $("#button1").on("click", clickEvent);
}
addClickEvent(1);
```

but it doesn't mean if your param is kinda object you can't do this. just the solution would differe, like:

```
function addClickEvent(param){
    window._allParams=[];
    var pindex =_allParams.push(param) - 1;
    var clickEvent=Function('var param =window._allParams['+pindex+']; alert(param);');
    $("#button1").on("click", clickEvent);
}
```

Comment: But... why? This feels like a horribly terrible way to do things

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
(function() {

 var args = arguments;

 function clickEvent(){
  return function(e) {
     return args; // [1,2,3,4];
  }();
 }

 keys.on('click',clickEvent);

})(1,2,3,4);
```

Answer (score -1):

just pass value where you are calling it

```
$("#button1").on("click", function(){clickEvent("1");});

function clickEvent(someParameter){
  console.log(someParameter);
}
```

when you need to pass value through function, you must pass while calling it, where you are already defining it at "someParameter" that you may pass some values to function. "someParameter" will act as variable inside function.

you can also use this function like this

```
var somevar = "1";

$("#button1").on("click", function(){clickEvent(somevar);});

function clickEvent(someParameter){
console.log(someParameter);
}
```

Comment: **-1** Nope, this does not work, because you're _not calling_ it, the event is

Comment: Have you noticed how this logs before you click, and doesn't log _when_ you click?

Comment: Corrected, Working now